# Is it possible using Bootstrap to always have menu collapsed showing burger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible using Bootstrap Nav to always show the nav menu as collapsed regardless of the width of the browser, and when the collapsed menu burger is clicked, then the menu drops down over the background but the full width of the browser window?

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <h1 class="navbar-brand">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-home"></i></a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#body">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cost">Cost</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it possible with a little extra CSS. You'll need to post the code you've attempted so far.

Comment: I have added the current code, it is only the default really bootstrap nav code though as not sure how to get what need to achieve hence my SO question.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: It is Boostrap 3.3.1 but theres nothing to stop me using bootstrap 4 and jquery 3.1.0